# Python - BaseHTTPServer do_GET() - wfile.write(filedata) Broken PIPE

Tags: python

I need to setup a Python web server which returns a few 3MB files. It uses baseHTTPServer to handle GET requests. How do you send a 3MB file using wfile.write() ?

```
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import BaseHTTPServer


class StoreHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    request_queue_size = 100

    def do_GET(self):
        try:

            filepath = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "tools"), "tools.zip")
            if not os.path.exists:
                print 'Tool doesnt exist'

            f = open(filepath, 'rb')
            file_data = f.read()
            f.close()

            self.send_header("Content-type", "application/octet-stream")
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(file_data) 
            self.send_response(200)
        except Exception,e:
            print e
            self.send_response(400)
```

Error:

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.0.6', 41025)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 279, in close
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Edit:

Client code:

```
import requests

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; FSL 7.0.5.01003)'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=60)
```

Comment: What kind of files are they? What is the operating system you are using? And which code are you using to start the server? (And what client are you using? browser? another python script?) Broken pipe happens when the client closes the socket that the server is trying to write to - maybe the client disconnected before the end?

Comment: Zip files, client = WIndows 7 and server is Ubuntu. Both client and server are python scripts were the client uses the requests module and the server uses basehttpserver to handle requests.

Answer (score 3):

You were not that far from a correct server...

You simply did not respect HTTP protocol with the order of your commands: the first command **must** be the `send_response` (or `send_error`), followed by other eventual header, then `end_header` and the data.

Also you are loading the whole file in memory, when it is not necessary. Your `do_GET` method could be:

```
def do_GET(self):
    try:

        filepath = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "tools"), "tools.zip")
        if not os.path.exists:
            print 'Tool doesnt exist'

        f = open(filepath, 'rb')

        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "application/octet-stream")
        self.end_headers()
        while True:
            file_data = f.read(32768) # use an appropriate chunk size
            if file_data is None or len(file_data) == 0:
                break
            self.wfile.write(file_data) 
        f.close()
    except Exception,e:
        print e
        self.send_response(400)
```